# Copy Text across Columns with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column in an excel workbook that contains an 'output example' and another column that contains a definition. I need the output example to be in the definition. So I wrote a macro that puts the phrase "Ex:" at the end of the text, then copies the text from the adjacent column and paste's it after the "Ex:"

```
   Sub Exampletransfer()
'
' Exampletransfer Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+E
'
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "The age range, in years of a customer. Ex: "
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1-4"
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "The age range, in years of a customer. Ex: 1-4"
    Range("H3").Select
End Sub
```

I attached a photo. I need this to happen to the whole column. I guess I don't understand how to get a macro to continue down a column.

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJx5W.png)
[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF6V4.png)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. Make sure you change where you data starts, in both the Range and the Cells method!

```
Sub AppendData()

Dim myRange As range
Dim myCell As range

'Change where you data starts. My practice started in B4, so that's
'what I used.
Set myRange = range("B4", Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp))


For Each myCell In myRange
    If myCell.Value <> "" Then
        myCell.Value = myCell.Value & " Ex: " & myCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
Next myCell


End Sub
```